# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rack": In Gemfile:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My ruby version is 1.9.3

I am trying to configure the redmine project to my system.

I installed all the required gems. But when i start the server it showing some error.

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rack":
In Gemfile:
rails (= 3.2.22) was resolved to 3.2.22, which depends on
  actionpack (= 3.2.22) was resolved to 3.2.22, which depends on
    rack (~> 1.4.5)

poltergeist was resolved to 1.0.0, which depends on
  capybara (~> 1.1) was resolved to 1.1.4, which depends on
    rack (>= 1.0.0)

rack-openid was resolved to 1.4.2, which depends on
  rack (>= 1.1.0)

poltergeist was resolved to 1.0.0, which depends on
  capybara (~> 1.1) was resolved to 1.1.4, which depends on
    rack-test (>= 0.5.4) was resolved to 0.6.3, which depends on
      rack (>= 1.0)
```

I don't know what to do... My rack version is 1.6.4

Comment: How do you know that your rack version is `1.6.4`?

Comment: If in your Gemfile you explicitly set rack to rack `1.4.7` it should work.

Comment: I installed all rack version mentioned in the error. Then its not showing the error

Comment: a question. you say early in your question that you've installed all the required gems. Does this mean you installed them with the `gem install` commandline tool or that you've got them in your Gemfile and ran `bundle install`. If you're installing those gems from the commandline then that might be the issue. Installing them at the command line will get you the most recent (or specified) version. The gems defined in your gemfile may depend on a version of those gems that is not the most recent. Consider relying entirely on `bundle install`. It manages gem related dependencies for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your current version should work for other gems but if you see `rails` depends on

```
rack (~> 1.4.5)
```

which means it needs the version of `rack` between `1.4.0` to `1.4.9`

**Solution**

1. Explicitly mention version of `rack` in your `Gemfile`

   ```
   gem 'rack', '~> 1.4.5'
   ```

Or

2. Delete the gem version greater than `1.4.9`

   ```
   gem uninstall rack
   ```

   Then install the gem manually

   ```
   gem install rack -v 1.4.5
   ```

Comment: I would avoid explicitly installing gems using the `gem install` command. My approac would be to uninstall rack and then run your `bundle install`. Bundler is exceptional at managing gem dependencies.

Comment: When i start to install bundle its required ruby_dep for some gems but ruby_dep required ruby 2.22 but my project ruby version is ruby1.9.3... i don't know ... how to solve this?

Comment: you need to check the gem dependencies first check the Gemspec of the gem which is giving you error

Comment: and switch to proper version which is supported by ruby 1.9.3

Answer (score -3):

Please use `bundle install` to install all required gems